# building memcmp function in c

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I'm creating my own `memcmp` and I have a question.

Here is my code:

```
int my_memcmp(void *b, void *c, int len)
{
    unsigned char *p;

    p = b;
    c = b;
    while(len > 0)
    {
        if(b - c != 0)
            return (b - c);
        len--;
        b++;
        c++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char          *str;
    char          *str2;
    int           i;

    str = strdup("hello");
    str2 = strdup("hellop");
    i = my_memcmp(str, str2, 6);
    printf("%d\n", i);
}
```

The output is wrong 6299669 where it should be -112.

I think the error is with my casting of p = b and c = b.  Is that correct?

Comment: You'll have to dereference the pointers. Comparing the pointers themselves doesn't make sense. You're also missing a return after the while loop.

Comment: Note: This won't compile without arithmetic void-pointer-differencing supported by language extension on the C compiler in use (i.e. gnu C). Arithmetic on `void*` isn't part of the standard. You never even *use* `p` in your loop, and you never dereference the underlying bytes for comparison.

Comment: In addition to all the other things that are wrong in this code, the reason for your output is that `my_memcmp` is exiting the while loop and not returning anything, which means that the value of `i` is undefined.

Comment: ***Use a debugger.  Set a breakpoint at the top of your `my_memcmp` function, and step through your code.  The error will be OBVIOUS.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int my_memcmp(void *b, void *c, int len)
{
    unsigned char *p = b;
    unsigned char *q = c;

    while (len > 0)
    {
        if (*p != *q)
            return (*p - *q);
        len--;
        p++;
        q++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 I would also test `if (b == c)` before any of this and just return 0 if they're the same pointer. no harm on the O(n) and avoids checking `n` bytes for no reason.

Comment: Yes; that would be a valid improvement with the constant cost of a few machine cycles for the 0.001% case where you do actually compare a chunk of memory with itself.  I'm not sure whether that trade-off is actually favourable; I've not tried the measurements.  OTOH, it is probably not measurable, either.  If you need more performance, you use an assembler comparison, not enhanced C.

Comment: And this is a deliberately laconic answer — Ingo and Abelenky provided insight into what I did without explaining.

Comment: I agree. If this were performance-required for large-N-*invokes* I probably wouldn't do it, but then again, were that the case I also wouldn't code it standard function; I'd write it as inline-asm.

Answer (score 2):

There are some errors, `p = b` is none of them, because you have to dereference the pointers (using `*`) to compare the contents. But as you can't dereference `void *` casting is neccessary. But you need two `unsigned char *p, *q` for `b` and `c` (the line `c = b` makes no sense at all), dereference p and q for comparing and increment `p` and `q`. Putting all together, you get the code that ... oops Jonathan Leffer has posted just now :-)
I think I'll post this nevertheless because it provides some explanations

Answer (score 2):

your function returns `b-c` when there is a difference.  *Well done.*

What if both memory-blocks are entirely equal?  What does it return then?
*(where do you think that code is?)*
What ***should*** it return when everything is equal?